# Many to many relation django in post to signs to post

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-2.0

So I want to make a sign-ups model for my app. This model needs to have 2 fields, a post field and a users field. Both fields are a many 2 many relation with the User model and Post model. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Here is what I have:

this is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=250)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class SignUpPost(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

so many users can be signed up in a post. I have no idea how to do the forms.py and the views.py to store the data.

I want to have in the post detail view a "sign up" button, and when clicked, fill the sign up form with the data of the post and user that clicked the button. And so, the database will have in the post field the post_id and in the users field the users_id of every user that signed up to the post.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not make an m2m in the `Post`s model named `signedup_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)`? Right now you are actually "wasting" an extra table for the m2m.

Comment: Right, now I see I was wasting an extra table. But now, I'm not so sure how to fill the signedup_users with the users_id. That has to be in the view of the Post, I think, but do I have to make a form for that?, how can I make the "sign up" button fill that field?